# Keyboard Traversal vs Accessibility Switch Control

Tags: flutter, keyboard-events, switchcontrol

Specifically, I am thinking in terms of a Flutter application but I believe this questions applies to any [accessibility switch control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201370) (there's an android and MacOS version as well) capable device and any keyboard based traversal device (web and desktop).

I'm wondering what the underlying mechanisms are for each of them? What's the difference between e.g. Flutter Focus System and Accessibility switch control's focus system? If they use similar underlying mechanisms, what are those mechanisms?